# Appending column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, vlookup

For the 3 columns below, I would like to create a 4th column based on unique values from the 3 columns.

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | : X : | Y : |
| X | : B : | Y : |
| C | : X : | X : |

4th Column should have values of only A, B or C, as shown below. Please let me know how this can be done.

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | Y | A |
| X | B | Y | B |
| C | X | X | C |

Comment: I don't understand the logic. What makes A, B and C unique?

Comment: It is like a vlookup in excel. Column 4 should filter only unique values from Columns 1, 2 and 3. For example, Col-4 should select only A, B, or C from Columns 1, 2, or 3. All other values (like X or y) should not get select in Column-4.

Answer (score -1):

If unique means unique values in all columns with join multiple unique values per rows use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) with aggregate `join`:

```
c = ['Col 1','Col 2','Col 3']
df['Col 4'] = df[c].stack().drop_duplicates(keep=False).groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)

print (df)
  Col 1 Col 2 Col 3 Col 4
0     A     X     Y     A
1     X     B     Y     B
2     C     X     X     C
```

---

```
print (df)
  Col 1 Col 2 Col 3 Col 4
0     A     X     Y     A
1     X     B     Y     B
2     C     X     D     C

c = ['Col 1','Col 2','Col 3']
df['Col 4'] = df[c].stack().drop_duplicates(keep=False).groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)

print (df)
  Col 1 Col 2 Col 3 Col 4
0     A     X     Y     A
1     X     B     Y     B
2     C     X     D   C,D
```

EDIT: If need extract only `A,B,C` values defined in list use:

```
L = ['A','B','C']

c = ['Col 1','Col 2','Col 3']
s  = df[c].stack()
df['Col 4'] = s[s.isin(L)].groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
print (df)
  Col 1 Col 2 Col 3 Col 4
0     A     X     Y     A
1     X     B     Y     B
2     C     X     X     C
```

Comment: This wasnt working. Depicting the table again for reference.

Comment: @Venkat - why is in first row unique value `A` and not `X, Y` ?

Comment: @Venkat - in another words - what means unique values?

Comment: I want to create a column based on a specific row value present in other columns. The new column should map select values from each row for either A, B or C present in the other columns. Hope this answers your query.

Comment: @Venkat - So it means if values is `A` or `B` or `C` is created new column with this value(s) ?

Comment: Yes Jezreal, that is correct.

Comment: @Venkat - answer was edited.